# HTML ,CSS Navigation Menu using images

Tags: html, css

I have an image 78x26 px that i want to use as buttons for my navigation bar.
What would be the most suitable way of doing this?

I want the image to keep its original size at the moment it doesnt

```
#navbar li {
    background-image:url("../images/btns.png");
}
```

Im aware that i can do something like this but then again how do i place the text over the images

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/btns.png"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also specify your width and height of the `<li>`.  Please try this:

```
#navbar li {
    background-image:url("../images/btns.png");
    width: 78px;
    height:26px;
}
```

`<li>` elements, I believe, are inline and therefore you must do something like this to make them appear side by side:

```
#navbar li {
        background-image:url("../images/btns.png");
        width: 78px;
        height:26px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: <li> elements are block elements and therefore require either display: inline-block; or float: left; if you want them to be placed horizontally next to each other AND ALSO recieve the width and height dimensions.

Comment: Good, glad to help; and +1 to Timidfriendly who pointed out that `<li>`'s are already block elements so you don't need to specify that twice (as shown in my edit).

Comment: @user1477388 How would i align the text so its in the middle of the image?

Comment: @Sebastian `text-align:center;`

Comment: @user1477388 Well that doesnt align it vertically

Comment: You would use `vertical-align: middle;` for that.

Comment: @user1477388 Thanks Which element should i use it on?

Comment: Strange, but please open a new question or try googling it.

Comment: @user1477388 Will do that thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` alone does not scale the image. If you feel like it's not rendering at the original size, it's probably because it's repeating.

use this instead:

```
background:url("../images/btns.png") no-repeat;
```

And then

```
<li><a href="#">Your text here</a></li>
```

You might now need to resize the `li` to fit your design

It could be better if you load your code online, like on codepen.io

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be the standards ways:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="menu-1"><a href="#">Menu-Link-text</a></li>
        <li class="menu-2"><a href="#">Menu-Link-text</a></li>
        ....
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

.navbar {
    overflow:hidden /* trick to force the navbar to wrap the floated <li>s */
} 
.main-nav li {
    float: left;
    display: inline; /* bug fix for older IE */
} 
.main-nav a {
    display:block; /* bigger click area */
    width: 78px;
    height:26px;
    text-indent: 100%; /* Text in the link for search engines and assistive technologies */
    whitespace: nowrap; /* see above */
    background: #yourFallBackBackgroundColor url("../images/btns.png") no-repeat 0 0; /* use a sprite with all images in one file and move them within background as required */
}
.menu-1 {
    background-position:0 0;
}
.menu-2 {
    background-position:-78px 0;
}
.menu-3 {
    background-position:-156px 0;
}
```